# HTTP multipart POST with parameters?

Tags: java, post, salesforce, multipartform-data, apex

```
curl --data "api_user=user&api_key=pwd&to=mymail@gmail.com&toname=Ram&subject=Testtt&from=othermail@gmail.com&text=testingtextbody&--form files[attachment.pdf]=@http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/pdf/java_strings.pdf;type=application/pdf" https://someendpoint.com/api/mail.send.xml
```

I have above the cURL command. I want to convert above call to HTTP multipart POST because above request has a pdf attachment. I am doing as below. Is my multipart POST request construction correct?

```
String boundary = 'delimiter';
  String header = '--'+boundary+'\n';  //boundary is random string
  String footer = '\n\n--'+boundary+'--'; // blank line separates body/footer
  String test='jjjjj';
  String bodyText = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[myfile.pdf]";\n'
                + 'filename="http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/pdf/java_strings.pdf"\n'
                + 'Content-Type: application/pdf\n\n' // Blank line separates header/body
                + test;


bodyText += '--'+boundary+'\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name ="api_user"\r\n\r\n superuser123';
bodyText += '--'+boundary+'\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name ="api_key"\r\n\r\n superpwd12345';
bodyText += '--'+boundary+'\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name ="to"\r\n\r\n myemail@gmail.com';
bodyText += '--'+boundary+'\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name ="from"\r\n\r\n someother@gmail.com';
bodyText += '--'+boundary+'\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name ="text"\r\n\r\n hellooooooooooooooooooooooooo';


  String body = header + bodyText + footer;
  HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

  req.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundary);
  req.setHeader('Content-Length',String.valueof(body.length()));
  req.setMethod('POST');
  req.setEndpoint('https://someendpoint.com/api/mail.send.xml');
  req.setBody(body);
  req.setTimeout(60000);
  Http http = new Http();
  HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
  System.debug('response:'+req.getBody());
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if it is correct, does it work or gives it errors?

Comment: CURL command works. The code gives wrong credentials error. I am not sure the request construction is proper.

Comment: How can your code work with single quote string?

Comment: It is Salesforce Apex language. Not Java. But the concept is same.

Answer (score 0):

Read the following articles on this topic

[POST Mutipart/form-data with HttpRequest](http://blog.enree.co/2013/01/salesforce-apex-post-mutipartform-data.html)

[Mutipart/form-data with HttpRequest](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24108/post-multipart-without-base64-encoding-the-body#answer-33326)

Correct way of creation multipart/form-data request. I used this solution a few time with excellent result

```
public static void uploadFile(Blob file_body, String file_name, String reqEndPoint){
      // Repost of code  with fix for file corruption issue
      // Orignal code postings and explanations
      // http://enreeco.blogspot.in/2013/01/salesforce-apex-post-mutipartform-data.html
      // https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24108/post-multipart-without-base64-encoding-the-body
      // Additional changes commented GW: that fix issue with occasional corruption of files
      String boundary = '----------------------------741e90d31eff';
      String header = '--'+boundary+'\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="'+file_name+'";\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream';
      // GW: Do not prepend footer with \r\n, you'll see why in a moment
      // String footer = '\r\n--'+boundary+'--'; 
      String footer = '--'+boundary+'--';             
      String headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header+'\r\n\r\n'));
      while(headerEncoded.endsWith('='))
      {
       header+=' ';
       headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header+'\r\n\r\n'));
      }
      String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(file_body);
      // GW: Do not encode footer yet
      // String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));

      Blob bodyBlob = null;
      String last4Bytes = bodyEncoded.substring(bodyEncoded.length()-4,bodyEncoded.length());

      // GW: Replacing this entire section
      /*
      if(last4Bytes.endsWith('='))
      {
           Blob decoded4Bytes = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(last4Bytes);
           HttpRequest tmp = new HttpRequest();
           tmp.setBodyAsBlob(decoded4Bytes);
           String last4BytesFooter = tmp.getBody()+footer;   
           bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded.substring(0,bodyEncoded.length()-4)+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(last4BytesFooter)));
      }
      else
      {
            bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded);
      }
      */
     // GW: replacement section to get rid of padding without corrupting data
     if(last4Bytes.endsWith('==')) {
        // The '==' sequence indicates that the last group contained only one 8 bit byte
        // 8 digit binary representation of CR is 00001101
        // 8 digit binary representation of LF is 00001010
        // Stitch them together and then from the right split them into 6 bit chunks
        // 0000110100001010 becomes 0000 110100 001010
        // Note the first 4 bits 0000 are identical to the padding used to encode the
        // second original 6 bit chunk, this is handy it means we can hard code the response in
        // The decimal values of 110100 001010 are 52 10
        // The base64 mapping values of 52 10 are 0 K
        // See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 for base64 mapping table
        // Therefore, we replace == with 0K
        // Note: if using \n\n instead of \r\n replace == with 'oK'
        last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0,2) + '0K';
        bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0,bodyEncoded.length()-4) + last4Bytes;
        // We have appended the \r\n to the Blob, so leave footer as it is.
        String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
        bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded);
      } else if(last4Bytes.endsWith('=')) {
        // '=' indicates that encoded data already contained two out of 3x 8 bit bytes
        // We replace final 8 bit byte with a CR e.g. \r
        // 8 digit binary representation of CR is 00001101
        // Ignore the first 2 bits of 00 001101 they have already been used up as padding
        // for the existing data.
        // The Decimal value of 001101 is 13
        // The base64 value of 13 is N
        // Therefore, we replace = with N
        // Note: if using \n instead of \r replace = with 'K'
        last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0,3) + 'N';
        bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0,bodyEncoded.length()-4) + last4Bytes;
        // We have appended the CR e.g. \r, still need to prepend the line feed to the footer
        footer = '\n' + footer;
        String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
        bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded);              
      } else {
        // Prepend the CR LF to the footer
        footer = '\r\n' + footer;
        String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
        bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded);  
      }

      HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
      req.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundary);
      req.setMethod('POST');
      req.setEndpoint(reqEndPoint);
      req.setBodyAsBlob(bodyBlob);
      req.setTimeout(120000);

      Http http = new Http();
      HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
}
```